# Mapping Textures to World Z-Axis

Tags: texturing, texture-coordinates

I'd like to apply a texture to several objects and have it fade out with increasing world Z-height. Think something like a high-water mark after flooding staining all objects. I've played around with several approaches but none seem to work. I can get the effect I want on a single object, but if I drag that object in the Z direction the texture stays with the object; I want the texture to stay put so the object appears to be "swimming" through the texture. I'd like to do this with procedural textures. It seems like I could use a gradient texture to help with this, but no success so far.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry If I'm misunderstanding the question, but I think you can get what you want by using the *Position* output of a *Geometry* (shader) Node, connected to a *Separate XYZ*. It's hard to see from the (non-moving) example below, but you can translate the object on the Z in Object Mode, and the "cutoff" line stays at the same Z-height. Use something like this as your texture mask:

[image: GeometryZ]

Comment: This seems to work the way I want. I'll need to do some fiddling to alter the width of the gradient, place it properly, and so forth but this look like the core of what's required. Thanks.